# LinkedHashMap save order by key in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, collections

Is it possible to preserve order of keys insertion of LinkedHashMap in JPA ?
I am currently trying to use  @OrderColumn, but it isn't working.

Comment: A map does not have any order. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: LinkedHashMap has order, but it is being lost after loading from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not because this only works with Lists and your LinkedHashMap is not the type you will get when reading the entities. It will be something that is an implementation of java.util.Map

From the spec:

> 11.1.43 OrderColumn Annotation The OrderColumn annotation specifies a column that is used to maintain the persistent order of a list.